# Sobject reference using parent throws an error

Tags: apex, sobject

I am using the following SOQL in my code and I am getting an error: Variable does not exist: Parent. Can someone help as to what I may be doing wrong in the code? Thanks.

```
String s1 = 'Account';
String s2 = 'PermissionsModifyAllRecords';
string qry = 'SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, Parent.Profile.ID, ParentID, Parent.Label FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE SObjectType = ' + s1 + ' AND  ' + s2 + ' = True AND Parent.ProfileID=null';
    List<ObjectPermissions> permSetSR = New List<ObjectPermissions>();
    permSetSR = Database.query(qry);
for(PermissionSet psr : permSetSR)
{
            TestResults__c results = new TestResults__c();
            If (psr.Parent.Profile.ID == null)
            {
            results.Reference_Name__c = psr.Parent.Profile.Name;
            results.Reference_Type__c = 'Permission Set';
                    results.Reference_ID__c = psr.ParentID;
                        results.Test_Name__c = 'PermSet Account Object Permission Test';
                        insert results;
            }
            else 
                        {
            results.Reference_Name__c = psr.permissionset.profile.name;
            results.Reference_Type__c = 'Profile';
                    results.Reference_ID__c = psr.PermissionSet.Profile.ID;
                        results.Test_Name__c = 'Profile Account Object Permission Test';
                        insert results;
                        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a fairly typical mistake in your code; you forgot to "quote" a string value in your filter, causing the error you're seeing. I'm not entirely sure why wouldn't just hard-code this to an inline query, but to fix the immediate problem, change your code as follows:

```
string qry = 'SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, Parent.Profile.ID, ParentID, Parent.Label FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE SObjectType = :s1 AND  ' + s2 + ' = True AND Parent.ProfileID=null';
```

Doing this will cause Database.query to bind s1 into the query on execution and produce the correct results.

---

Also, you're querying ObjectPermissions, but later trying to iterate over the list as if it were a PermissionSet. You should get several errors, because you've defined your loop as the wrong type:

```
for(ObjectPermissions psr : permSetSR) {
```

Your compilation error occurs because Parent isn't a relationship on a PermissionSet, but the root cause was actually because the variable was the wrong data type.

---

Also, other typical notes apply here: do not DML inside of a loop, always prefer the ID field instead of a reference to the ID (e.g. `Parent.ProfileId` should be used instead of `Parent.Profile.Id`), and you might want to rethink your logic; it's currently impossible to test the "profile" path, because you're explicitly querying for only permission sets.

Comment: I am still a beginner in Apex. It would be great if you can give me hand in working on the logic. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks.